# I am getting this error" Error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) in Mysql", please resolve this issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Assignment:

> Display the name of the departments whose average salary is highest among the departments whose average salaries are less than the average salary of the company. [Hint: Use nested subqueries]

My attempt:

```
Select Department, avg(Salary) as "Highest Average Salary" 
from Employees 
group by Department 
having avg(Salary) > (
    select Department, avg(Salary) as "Average Salary" 
    from Employees 
    group by Department 
    having avg(Salary) < (select avg(Salary) from Employees));
```

Comment: You're returning 2 columns from the subquery. How can you compare `avg(Salary)` to two columns?

Comment: Also, the subquery could return more than one row. Which one do you want to compare `avg(Salary)` to?

Comment: What is this query supposed to return?

Comment: Why do you think you need to select `Department` in the subquery?

Comment: The question is basically this "Display the name of the departments whose average salary is highest among the departments whose average salaries are less than the average salary of the company.
[Hint: Use nested subqueries]"
Kindly resolve my issue.

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, please add all clarification to the question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase He posted his attempt, and the title contains the error he's getting from it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the subquery returns multiple columns, and potentially multiple rows. When you use a subquery as an expression, it must return only one column, and at most one row (if it returns zero rows the value is treated as `NULL`). You can't compare `AVG(Salary)` with multiple values.

The subquery is correct to find the departments whose average salaries are less than the average across the company. But you're not using it correctly in the main query.

You shouldn't be using it in a `WHERE` clause. You should put it in another subquery to get the maximum of the average ("average salary is the highest" in the exercise). You can then use that in a `HAVING` clause of the main query to find all the departments with that average salary.

```
SELECT Department
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Department
HAVING AVG(Salary) = (
    SELECT MAX(AvgSalary)
    FROM (
        select avg(Salary) as AvgSalary
        from Employees 
        group by Department 
        having AvgSalary < (select avg(Salary) from Employees)
    )
)
```